# gtag Purchase Event ignored on Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking, gtag.js

I'm succesfully tracking some [events](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event#top_of_page) with gtag.js on Google Analytics, with the exception of ["purchase" event](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event#purchase).
Using [GTM/GA chrome plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtmga-debug/ilnpmccnfdjdjjikgkefkcegefikecdc) I've checked that all events are tracked correctly, "purchase" included.
The problem is that "purchase" is not tracked on Google Analytics: all the others are tracked ("begin_checkout", "add_to_cart" ...).

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
  affiliation: "Google online store",
  coupon: "SUMMER_DISCOUNT",
  currency: "USD",
  shipping: 5.55,
  tax: 3.33,
  transaction_id: "T_1",
  value: 28.86,
  items: [
    {
      id: "P12345",
      name: "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      coupon: "P12345_coupon",
      list_name: "Search Results",
      brand: "Google",
      category: "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      variant: "Black",
      list_position: 3,
      quantity: 1,
      price: 9.99
    },
    {
      id: "P12346",
      name: "Flame challenge TShirt",
      coupon: "P12346_coupon",
      list_name: "Search Results",
      brand: "MyBrand",
      category: "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      variant: "Red",
      list_position: 5,
      quantity: 1,
      price: 9.99
    }
  ]
});
```

The conversion/e-commerce graph is flat as you can see. What am I missing?
[image]

**Update**
I've created a GAnalytics test account and the purchase event is tracked. On the screenshot's account, maybe, some configuration is missing: could be?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem.
Some things I noticed that could explain ut.

1. **Date Range**: Maybe you missed the fact that the date range in your Analytics
   report is set for 26 Oct - 1 Nov, while your events were triggered
   on 2 Nov?
2. **Wrong Value Field**: If the calculation of the value field is wrong (does not equal total of all items plus shipping field plus tax field) Google might ignore the event.
3. **Processing Time**: Even when the "Real-Time" view shows the events, they are
   not always included in other reports until some time later.

Comment: Sometimes, I send events where the total of all items is not equal to the value with tax and shipping because there is a coupon code applied (the `coupon` field is just a string so there is no way for Google to validate the total). Nevertheless, the events are valid since I see them in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 2):

### Interestingly I'm seeing something similar on my tests and I'm using some sample code off google:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXX-Y"></script>
<script nonce="djRFUUKP+SLF1k4qkKFqiLTO4Qo=">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments); }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXX-Y');
    </script>

    <script nonce="djRFUUKP+SLF1k4qkKFqiLTO4Qo=">
    gtag('event', 'purchase', {
    "transaction_id": "24.031608523954162_C",
    "affiliation": "Google online store_C",
    "value": 0.01,
    "currency": "GBP",
    "tax": 1.24,
    "shipping": 0,
    "items": [
    {
      "id": "P12345C",
      "name": "Android Warhol T-Shirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "Google",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Black",
      "list_position": 1,
      "quantity": 2,
      "price": '0.01'
    },
    {
      "id": "P67890C",
      "name": "Flame challenge TShirt",
      "list_name": "Search Results",
      "brand": "MyBrand",
      "category": "Apparel/T-Shirts",
      "variant": "Red",
      "list_position": 2,
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": '3.0'
    }
    ]
    });
    </script>
```

We use nonce because we are using CSP and believe all CSP urls are set correctly in the CSP.

Any insight would be a great help as to why this would not be logging this transaction data.

Comment: Note that the `value` parameter of your purchase event is smaller than the total of all the items. From my experience google might decide to ignore the event because of that.

Comment: Note that if you specify the `coupon` field, the total can be smaller that the total of all items. It's not the case in your code snippet though, but the `price` is a string, it should be an integer (`price: 3` instead of `price: '3.0'`).

Answer (score 1):

Just found that:

`"transaction_id": "-1",`

will also be hard ignored by GA4, even in debug_mode. So if you're testing, developing or debugging it will get picked up if you insert "TEST" (or anything else for that matter) before it.

```
gtag("event", "purchase", { debug_mode: true,
    transaction_id: "TEST-1",
...
```

Answer (score -2):

For `Item Data:`, id should be the *transaction ID*.
See here:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce#item

Comment: The link you provided is the documentation for analytics.js and not gtag.js. In the gtag documentation, the `id` is described as `The product ID or SKU`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce#product-data